# Italian fiscal code validation/control - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, controls, primeng

Could someone tell me how to check fiscal code (at least for name and surname) in Angular?

EXAMPLE -->

name: Lorenzo

lastname: Rossi

How do I check that I have correctly entered the consonants of the name and lastname in the fiscal code?

fiscal code: RSSLRN87A14L219U. At least **RSSLRN** is right?

Unfortunately I don't have a reactive form. This is my HTML.

```
<div class="col-4">
          <div>Codice fiscale</div>
          <span class="p-float-label">
            <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Inserisci codice fiscale" 
               name="codiceFiscale"
              [(ngModel)]="data.fiscalCode"
              pattern="^([A-Za-z]{6}[0-9lmnpqrstuvLMNPQRSTUV]{2} 
              [abcdehlmprstABCDEHLMPRST]{1}[0-9lmnpqrstuvLMNPQRSTUV]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0- 
               9lmnpqrstuvLMNPQRSTUV]{3}[A-Za-z]{1})$|([0-9]{11})$"
              onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==16) return false;"/>
          </span>
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the full validation of an Italian fiscal code, then you can use this regex:

```
'^[A-Za-z]{6}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{3}[A-Za-z]{1}$'
```

In your code:

```
<div class="col-4">
            <div>Codice fiscale</div>
            <span class="p-float-label">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    pInputText
                    placeholder="Inserisci codice fiscale"
                    name="codiceFiscale"
                    [(ngModel)]="data.fiscalCode"
                    [pattern]="'^[A-Za-z]{6}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{3}[A-Za-z]{1}$'"
                    onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==16) return false;">
            </span>
        </div>
```

reference: https://regex101.com/r/yRZnlG/1